# Badge view how to create with a full auto layout approach

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

It's been a while since I'm trying to create a custom view that has at the top right corner a simple badge.
The custom view is composed by 3 part.

1. In *red* there is the *custom view* itself, that contains:
2. in *blue* the *container view*
3. in *green* the *badge view* a simple `UILabel`

Container view and the badge view are sibling.
 
At the moment the container view contains a `UIImageView`

[image]

That view **must** fit those requirements:

1. Full auto layout approach
2. Made programmatically
3. The **custom view must be aligned only considering the blue frame**(the container view)

Why that? imagine that you need to position that view by aligning the top edge to the top edge of another view or button, wouldn't be nice if the only the content showed int he container is taken into account?
Here you can see how I set the constraints. The label is placed at the top right corner of the container view.

```
func setUpConstraint() {
        var horContraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
        horContraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: containerView, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        horContraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: containerView, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: badge, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        horContraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: badge, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        var verContraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
        verContraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: containerView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        verContraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: containerView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: badge, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        verContraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: badge, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        addConstraints(verContraints + horContraints)        
        containerView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: containerView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
}
```

The container view has also an aspect ratio constraint to keep a square size.
As you can see from the picture everything seems to be fine, except for the fact that when I try to constraint the custom view to the center of its superview, it *seems misaligned, because I want the view to be centered respect to the container view (the one with the image)*. The badge is a kind of decoration such as a shadow and I don't want it to be consider.

[image]
To align it correctly I'm trying to override the alignment rect by adding an insets that would "cut" half the label size.

```
   override func alignmentRectInsets() -> UIEdgeInsets {
        let badgeSize = badge.bounds.size
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: badgeSize.height / 2, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: badgeSize.width / 2)
    }
```

I tried also different configurations but I never was able to fit in the wanted position 

[image]
If I try to use the other 2 methods `alignmentRectForFrame` and `frameForAlignmentRect` (deleting `alignmentRectInsets`) they are never be called.
Here is what I'd like to obtain:
[image]
I've created a [little sample code](https://github.com/DrAma999/TestAlignmentRect/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is that you want the *other* view (the "content view", showing the image) to be centered in the ultimate superview, then simply make centering constraints (center x to center x, center y to center y) between the superview and the content view. No law says that a constraint has to be between a view and its direct superview; you can make constraints between *any* pair of views (that is one of the wonderful things about constraints).

I made a quick mock-up that looks a lot like your "here's what I'd like to obtain" image:

[image]

As you can see, Moe (the middle Pep Boy, in the middle of the image) is exactly centered in the superview (shown by the green lines).

For simplicity, the *entire* interface is created in code, so that I can show you the whole thing. Here it is:

```
// create the custom view
let customView = UIView()
customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.view.addSubview(customView)
customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
    customView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(100),
    customView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(100),
    ])

// add the content view (image) to the custom view
let contentView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named:"pep.jpg")!)
contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
customView.addSubview(contentView)
NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
    contentView.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(customView.leadingAnchor),
    contentView.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(customView.bottomAnchor),
    contentView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(customView.heightAnchor, constant: -10),
    contentView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(customView.widthAnchor, constant: -10)
    ])

// add the badge (label) to the custom view
let badge = UILabel()
badge.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
customView.addSubview(badge)
badge.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)
badge.font = UIFont(name: "GillSans", size: 14)
badge.textAlignment = .Center
badge.text = "567"
NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
    badge.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(contentView.trailingAnchor),
    badge.centerYAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(contentView.topAnchor),
    ])


// position the whole thing with respect to the content view
NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
    contentView.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.centerXAnchor),
    contentView.centerYAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.centerYAnchor),
    ])
```

---

But this is not a complete answer to your question. You should now be asking: Yes, but what went wrong when I tried to use the `alignmentRectInsets`? The answer is: you forgot that the `alignmentRectInsets` affect alignment with *internal* views as well as *external* views. In other words, you certainly can use that approach instead, but then you must adjust the position of the content view accordingly.

So, here's a rewrite in which I use the `alignmentRectInsets`. First, I'll define a custom view subclass for our custom view:

```
class AlignedView : UIView {
    override func alignmentRectInsets() -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 0, 0, 10)
    }
}
```

Now here's the rewrite. I've put a star (`*`) next to all the lines that have *changed* from the previous example:

```
// create the custom view
let customView = AlignedView() // *
customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.view.addSubview(customView)
customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
    customView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(100),
    customView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(100),
    ])

// add the content view (image) to the custom view
let contentView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named:"pep.jpg")!)
contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
customView.addSubview(contentView)
NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
    contentView.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(customView.leadingAnchor),
    contentView.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(customView.bottomAnchor),
    contentView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(customView.heightAnchor), // *
    contentView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(customView.widthAnchor) // *
    ])

// add the badge (label) to the custom view
let badge = UILabel()
badge.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
customView.addSubview(badge)
badge.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)
badge.font = UIFont(name: "GillSans", size: 14)
badge.textAlignment = .Center
badge.text = "567"
NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
    badge.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(contentView.trailingAnchor),
    badge.centerYAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(contentView.topAnchor),
    ])


// position the whole thing with respect to the custom view

NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
    customView.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.centerXAnchor), // *
    customView.centerYAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.centerYAnchor), // *
    ])
```

That gives exactly the same visual result as before.

Comment: But I must admit I don't really understand what you're after. It might help if you drew a picture of what you _want_ rather than showing pictures of what you're _getting_.

Comment: hello, thank you for your suggestion, I've edited the question. Even if I try to inverse the inset it doesn't seems to work. The alignment rect still consider the label. Actually it doesn't seems to change nothing except for the frame of the custom view. I've created a sample code https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51180713/TestActivateDeactivate.zip

Comment: Well, perhaps I am just abnormally dense, but I have still not understood what the issue is. When I think I might understand what you want to do, I don't understand why it's hard. I don't grasp what the views are to which you are referring by all these names. Perhaps it would help me if you would reduce the whole problem to a very simple minimal project, post it on github, and make clear what's wrong with the resulting interface. That way, I could just try to edit the project itself.

Comment: thank you, I'm sorry if I wasn't clear about the issue. The fact is that it really seams easy also to myself, I do not understand what I'm missing or misunderstood about alignment rect. I've created a github project as you suggested trying to clean all the unnecessary code and fully reviewed the question https://github.com/DrAma999/TestAlignmentRect/

Comment: I'm still here...! Okay, now this is what I don't understand. You say: "except for the fact that when I try to constraint the custom view to the center of its superview, it seems misaligned" and then you show a picture. But in that picture, it looks perfect to me: the custom view (red) has its center in the center of the superview. If it is not where you want it, where _do_ you want it? You can easily compensate by using the `constant` component of the centering constraints (not the alignment stuff, that's irrelevant). I've added that to my answer...

Comment: Me too :D, ok good, now I get. In the first 3 points, I say that I'd like the view to be centered in the blue container view (the one that contains the image). The last image I posted shows what I'd like to achieve, basically I don't want   part of the label to be taken into account.

Comment: Then simply apply your centering constraint between the superview _and the content view_ (the image), not between the superview and the custom view (red) as you are doing now. — Again, I've added that to my answer.

Comment: thanks again for you suggestion I agree with your point, but this component will be UIView subclass (also IBDesignable) and I don't want to expose inner subviews. As you know, if I take a view in the xib rename its class I do not have any knowledge of the inner subviews, neither the possibility to constraint one of them to the outer world . Wasn't alignment rect supposed to be used in that case? like "hacking" the alignment rect?

Comment: Okay, I've added code to demonstrate how to do this in both ways: centering with respect to the content view, and centering with respect to the custom view when the custom view has custom alignment rect.

Comment: "and I don't want to expose inner subviews" Yes, I thought you might say that. :) That is why I added another solution where we use the alignment rect, and so the inner workings of the custom view are completely opaque - it can just be centered directly. If you like, I can rewrite it again so that all the subview creation is moved into the custom view class, but surely you can see how to do that... :)

Comment: I'm so grateful for the explanation!!!!! In Italy we say "sei un mito"(you are a myth) Grazie!

Comment: Thank you, but it was fun for me to help - I'm sorry it took me so long to understand what the problem was.